# Max number (not max digits) in HTML pattern

Tags: html, regex, validation, pattern-matching, html-input

I'd like to have a simple html-input, which validates the edition-number of a magazine via HTML5 (no worry, it's re-checked server-sided anyway).

The format shall be **EDITIONNUMBER/YEAR**. The magazine appears *monthly*, so beside the max-digit of 2 (correct is 1/2019 and 12/2018) it should have a maximal number of 12 (13/2018 never exists). So my problem is **not** to find out, how to set up the max digit number, but a maximum number in a pattern for HTML5.

Everything >=1 and <=12 should be correct before /YYYY.

So far I use this one, which at least checks for 0/0000 or 00/0000. In my case it's not necessary to check the correct date format, because that's also validated with php [checkdate](https://secure.php.net/manual/function.checkdate.php), but the number of the edition should be right in the first step.

```
<input type="text" pattern="[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{4}">
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try using the pattern:

```
([1-9]|1[0-2])/[0-9]{4}
```

The above pattern uses an alternation for the edition number to either match 1-9 (on the left side), or 10-12 (on the right side).  This can then be followed by any 4 digit year.

In your code:

```
<input type="text" pattern="([1-9]|1[0-2])/[0-9]{4}">
```